# Resource Controllers creation issues by artisan

Tags: php, laravel

I have create a fresh installation

Dir Structure:

```
test_bb/laravel
               / app
               / ....
```

I created a resourceful controller in laravel by

```
php artisan controller:make PhotoController
```

and put `Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');` in **routes.php**

But when i try to access `hostname/photo`
It shows “The requested URL /photo was not found on this server.” and shows error pen:

```
C:\wamp\www\test_bb\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `http://hostname`? Does `http://hostname/index.php/photo` works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the project's root folder

Artisan comes with Laravel by default, if your php command works fine, then the only thing you need to do is to navigate to the project's root folder. The root folder is the parent folder of the app folder. For example:

```
cd c:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\your-project-name
```

then run

```
c:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\your-project-name>php artisan controller:make MyController
```

njoy!!.